# Single Instance only .NET Web Service

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asmx

I have a particular asmx WebMethod that I want to limit to one running instance at a time.

The reason is that it reads data from database, reads data from a file, process the data, sends emails, and then stores data back to the database and I'm concerned that if two instances are running at one time it could cause problems.

Is there a way to enforce this?

```
[WebMethod]
public List<string> MyMethod()
{
    using (myEntities context = new myEntities())
    {
        //read database, files and do other stuff here
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Or maybe I can force a lock on the database so that only one thread can be inside the using statement?

**Current Solution:**

```
[WebMethod]
public List<string> MyMethod()
{
    List<string> log = new List<string>();
    if(!Monitor.TryEnter(_syncRoot)) {
        log.Add("Proccess Currently Running");
        return log;
    }
    try
    {
        using (myEntities context = new myEntities())
        {
            //doStuff
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        log.Add("Success"); 
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        log.Add(ex.Message);
    } finally {
        Monitor.Exit(_syncRoot);
    }
    return log;
}
```

**Note:**

My current solution seems inadequate for the case where I have multiple servers running, which I do. Maybe obtain a table lock on the table, and if I'm unable to obtain the lock, throw an exception. Can I do this?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN. Among other reasons to use WCF, it has the ability to be single-instance.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. You or someone else lets me know this almost everytime I post a question about asmx.

Comment: I or someone else lets _all readers_ know it every time you post a question about asmx. It's not all about _you_.

Comment: Your clearly missing my point. It has nothing to do with me.

Comment: I'm reacting to your use of the word "me", as in "you or someone else lets _me_ know"

Comment: I was hoping to emphasis the word "everytime". There are a lot of things I would like to change about the technologies my company uses. I'm well aware we should be using WCF and hopefully that will happen sooner than later.

Comment: Again, the use of "I". Your questions are hopefully read by many people, and the answers will help many people. My comment isn't only addressed at you: it's addressed at all future readers, many of whom may not know that ASMX is a legacy technology. You'd be surprised how many people learn by Google, and search for ".NET Web Services" and find articles from 2002 on ASMX, and decide that's the way to go.

Comment: It's not the message your trying to that is the problem so much as it is the way that you portray it. It comes off somewhat condescending. However, if you know of a way WCF can ensure a single instance across multiple servers I would be really interested in learning more about that.

Comment: Across multiple servers? Your question didn't state that, and no, WCF has no built-in way to do that. You would have to use a database, or some other mechanism which depends on a persistent store.

Comment: I'll update the question, it was mentioned in a comment below. I'm hoping that maybe I can just get a table lock on the table I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

At the simplest level you can just make use of `lock()` on a static object within your webserver.  This will ensure that the second request is queued, but will not stop it from running.

```
public static object _syncRoot = new object();
[WebMethod]
public List<string> MyMethod()
{
    lock (_syncRoot) {
    using (myEntities context = new myEntities())
        {
          //read database, files and do other stuff here
          context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

The next level of complexity is to try and obtain a lock using [Monitor.TryEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.tryenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), timeout and display an error page.

```
[WebMethod]
public List<string> MyMethod()
{   
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(_syncRoot, 5000)) {
        throw new TimeoutExpiredException();
    }
    try {
        // ...
    } finally {
        // Exit the lock if it was obtained
        Monitor.Exit(_syncRoot);
    }
}
```

It's important to note that this will only work on a single instance webserver - if you're using a cluster, the static object won't be shared between web requests and this won't work.  You'll need to use something in the database in this case.

Comment: I like this! How can I try to obtain the lock so that I can return a "Process currently running" message. In the end the return value of this method is just going to be a message for a log file saying what happened.

Comment: I've already updated the answer to include throwing an exception if you didn't obtain the lock within 5 seconds.  You can adapt this to whatever you like.

Comment: Great, thanks. If I set it to 0, then it will just immediately  go to the exception?

Comment: Check the documentation for [Monitor.TryEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.tryenter(v=vs.110).aspx).  You can use Monitor.TryEnter(_syncRoot) (no number) for it not to wait.

Comment: OK great, thanks. I updated my question with the solution I'm looking at it. I think it looks pretty Kosher. Thanks!

Comment: Just saw your note relating to the single instance web server. We generally have two web servers running our code.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you store a flag in the database when you begin the process the first time, and for all others, it can exit immediately like:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<string> MyMethod()
    {
        using (myEntities context = new myEntities())
        {
              if (/* check if flag set in db table */) {
                   return null; //exit and don't allow anyone else to use
              }

              //read database, files and do other stuff here

              //set flag to false
              context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

This may be beneficial because it also allows for an external process to also trigger the same action, and can then prevent the UI from doing anything.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind in case I find I need to do this from another process other than this WebMethod and want to make sure they both don't run at the same time. Thanks.

Comment: Can I just have sql lock the table instead? And then if a second instance tries to run it won't be able to get the table lock?

Comment: Look at using a hint, provided here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213026(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Ya, I'm familiar with hints, however, I'm not aware that you can use them with EF. I ended up using a transaction scope I found on another question.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a transaction with a setting of Serializable.

When I ran this multiple times simultaneously, I got a mix of:

- the process falling into both exception handlers
- the process waiting and executing after

Either way, two processes did not run at the same time leaving my database intact :)

```
[WebMethod]
    public List<string> MyMethod()
    {
        var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable, Timeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue };
        try
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (myEntities context = new myEntities())
                    {
                    //doStuff
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }catch (Exception ex) {
                    //handle database exception here
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception ex){
            //handle transaction scope exception here
        }
        return new List<string>();
    }
```